# Should I use the Google Vision API or an OCR package from npm?

Tags: node.js, ocr

I'm just wondering what the best option is for my project:
A mobile app that rates how healthy a user's food is. It works by looking at the image the user took for text detection. I'm fairly new to programming and know very little about back end development in Node.js. What would you recommend for an easy API or package with accurate text detection?